# How do I prompt my alert to the user with a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, contacts

I want to make a contact form using php and javascript and I'm having a hard time with the alert() function. What I want to do, is inform the user of what's happening in the back end. I noticed that my "echo" functions get prompted into the console and I want to make them visible as an alert() function.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    console.log("button clicked");
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var adresse = $("#adresse").val();
    var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var project_place = $("#project_place").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
    // Checking for blank fields.
    if (name == '' || email == '' || telephone == '' || message == '') {
      alert("Please fill out the required fields.");
    } else {
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    $.post("includes/mail.php", {
      name1: name,
      adresse1: adresse,
      telephone1: telephone,
      email1: email,
      project_place1: project_place,
      message1: message
      }, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      $("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message paragraph.
      if (data == "Email sent.") {
         $("#frmContact")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
         alert("Email sent.");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

and here's my php:

```
<?php
// Fetching Values from URL.
$name = $_POST['name1'];
$adresse = $_POST['adresse1'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
$lieu_du_projet = $_POST['lieu_du_projet1'];
$message = $_POST['message1'];
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.

// After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $telephone)) {
      echo "Please, enter a valid number";
    } else {
        $subject = $name;
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "rn";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $email. "rn"; // Sender's Email
        $headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "rn"; // Carbon copy to Sender
        $template = 'Hi ' . $nom . ","
        . "\n\nThank you form contacting us,"
        . "\nName: " . $name
        . "\nAdresse: " . $adresse
        . "\nTelephone: " . $telephone
        . "\nEmail: " . $email
        . "\nProject Place: " . $project_place
        . "\nMessage: " . $message
        . "\nThis is a confirmation email. "
        . "\nWe'll get back to you as soon as possible";
        $sendmessage =  $template ;
        // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
        $sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
        // Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
        mail("my@email.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
        echo "Email sent.";
        }
    } else {
    echo "Email invalid.";
    }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: looks like you just need to add a `alert(data)` to your ajax success function

Comment: ... or on a `done` callback for the newest jQuery version. Anyway, except that I assume that you verified that the AJAX request is valid and it returns a valid response? Also using alert nowadays is considered an old-school approach, isn't it nicer to use some info-box or styled modal?